# Is Kefura super saiyan 2 a regular super saiyan 2 transformation?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

Kefura super saiyan 2 transformation doesnt look exactly the same than a regular super saiyan 2 transformation. Is it supposed to be the same kind of transformation aside the differences? Besides the different hair color, to me Kefura SSJ2 seems to have more sparks than a regular SSJ2 transformation

Caulifla super saiyan 2

[image]

Kefura super saiyan 2

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Isn´t her name Kefla? or is this a "dub" mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kefla seems to utilize Kale's powers over Goku. Kale's initial SSJ transformation seems to have a tinge of green just like Kefla's did. Also, Kale in her SSJ state was shown to be on the same level as SSJ2 Caulifla despite the SSJ2 multiplier being a higher one. We know Kale in her mastered LSSJ form was a lot stronger than SSJ2 Caulfila. I believe the two transformations Kefla used aren't exactly the regular SSJ transformations like the one Vegito used in the Buu Saga against Buuhan.

Vegito SSJ2 is weaker than SSJG Goku. We know this from the battle of gods arc where Goku stated that he couldn't defeat Beerus even if he were to fuse with Vegeta. Base Kefla was a lot stronger than SSJG Goku. So I would say, the SSJ and SSJ2 transformations used by Kefla are special variations of Kale's LSSJ Transformation which is the reason she seems to be a lot more stronger

Comment: Yes this is true . Kefla's SSJ2 , was legendary super saiyan 2 and not the normal ssj2 .

Comment: May be something in between legendary super saiyan and traditional super saiyan? Since she's the combination of 2 characters?

Answer (score 1):

Kefla's SSJ2 form is indeed **not** your regular SSJ2. This is because a lot variable factors are used which we should keep in mind. These are caused by the fusion of 2 Saiyans with different forms. Kale is using her Legendary/Berserk SSJ forms which emit a green aura. These forms bring a close to infinite pool of power and ki. Caulifla on the other hand is able to utulize SSJ2 pretty well. This form can be recognized by the lightning sparks and the violent aura that covers the whole body and clothes. SSJ itself has a rather calm aura without any lightning sparks, with ofcourse almost the same hairstyle.

Now to get back to Kefla in the screenshots you provided we can see 3 important things.

1. Green aura (Kale's LSSJ/BSSJ)
2. Lightning sparks (SSJ2 in general)
3. Violent covering aura (SSJ2 in general)

So with these observations it is safe to assume that the most accurate name to this form would be LSSJ2. This is because Kale was able to master her BSSJ, making it the LSSJ. This in combination with the SSJ2 from Caulifla delivers us the breathtaking LSSJ2.

Answer (score -1):

It isn't supposed to be different, **rather its a whole new form of SSJ2!**.
This form of SSJ2 is the merged transformation of SSJ2 of Caulifla + LSSJ2 Kale. Though we know Kale's LSSJ2 isn't official, I rather am reffering to their fused SSJ2 form.
This is evident that when 2 person fuse either by potara rings or Fusion Dance, they either use a transformation that both fused person have attained
or they either attain a new form in the fusion state(which is applied to Kefla's case) where the both persons gain this new form.

For E.g.
Gogeta's SSB = Goku SSB + VEGITA SSB(POWER IS NOT SAME,BUT I AM TRYING TO SAY GOGETA'S SSB IS RESULT OF  FUSION OF GOKU'S SSB +VEGETA'S SSB + ADDED FUSION POWER)(ALSO NOTE THAT BOTH GOKU AND VEGETA HAVE ACTAULLY MASTERED SSB)
[image: Gogeta SSB]

Now lets see kefla's case:
Kale already had mastery over her LSSJ, and caulifla had mastery over SSJ2,
so their fusion first gave rise to "KEFLA", then this "KEFLA" attained "LSSJ"(Legendary Super Saiyan) and then "KEFLA" attained "LSSJ2"(Legendary Super Saiyan 2/LSSJ who have ascended past LSSJ) as the new form of commbination of LSSJ with SSJ2.
[image: Now notice Kefla's hair in SSJ form]

[image: Notice how they increase much, so this is new LSSJ2 form!]

Now u can notice the difference in the hair of Kefla SSJ and Kefla SSJ2 or rather Kefla's LSSJ and Kefla's LSSJ2!

THANKS FOR HEARING ME!